# Cannot Add Tuple to BlockingCollection: Error CS1503 in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, tuples, blockingcollection

I'm working on a project that involves object detection with real-time video in C#. As part of the project, I use a BlockingCollection to manage a list of bounding boxes for detected objects, and the details for each bounding box are held in a tuple. However, I'm encountering an error CS1503 when trying to add new tuples to the collection. Here's how I defined the BlockingCollection:

```
BlockingCollection<Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, Scalar, DateTime>> ObjectDetectionBbox = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, Scalar, DateTime>>();
```

And here's the line where I'm trying to add a new tuple to the collection:

```
ObjectDetectionBbox.Add(Tuple.Create(
    topLeft.X,                        
    topLeft.Y,                        
    bottomRight.X - topLeft.X,        
    bottomRight.Y - topLeft.Y,        
    className,                        
    trackedName,                      
    classColor,                       
    bboxTimestamp                     
));
```

The error message is:

> Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, OpenCvSharp.Scalar, System.Tuple<System.DateTime>>' to 'System.Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, OpenCvSharp.Scalar, System.DateTime>'

The error message seems to suggest that my tuple has a Tuple as the last element, but as you can see in my code, the last element is a DateTime.

I've confirmed that bboxTimestamp is indeed a DateTime, and I'm not sure why this error is happening.
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I could fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### HERE IS THE FULL CODE FOR REFERENCE:

```
public async Task Main(System.Windows.Controls.Image imageControl, CancellationToken token)
        {
            BlockingCollection<Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, Scalar, DateTime>> ObjectDetectionBbox = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, Scalar, DateTime>>();
            BlockingCollection<Tuple<Mat, DateTime>> frameBuffer = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<Mat, DateTime>>(); // Our new frame buffer

            string cameraUrl = "http://cam1.infolink.ru/mjpg/video.mjpg";
            //string cameraUrl = "http://hotel-seerose.dyndns.org:8001/cgi-bin/faststream.jpg?stream=full&fps=0";
            string URLreturnBbox = "http://localhost:8003/api/v1/camera/get_frame";  // Updated endpoint URL
            await initializeRunServer(cameraUrl);
            var idFaceDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, object>();
            var classNames = await GetClassNames();
            var colorList = InitColorList(classNames.Count);

            Task processFrameTask = Task.Run(() => ProcessTask(imageControl, token, URLreturnBbox, classNames, colorList,idFaceDictionary, ObjectDetectionBbox));
            

            // Create video source
            MJPEGStream stream = new MJPEGStream(cameraUrl);


            // New frame event handler
            stream.NewFrame += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                // Convert AForge.NET's Bitmap to OpenCvSharp's Mat
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                Mat frame = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(bitmap);
                
                // Get bbox info from ObjectDetectionBbox, if any
                while (ObjectDetectionBbox.TryTake(out var bbox)) // Replace if with while to draw all available bounding boxes
                {
                    // Ensure we only proceed if there is a detection and a valid class name.
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bbox.Item5))
                    {
                        if (bbox.Item5 == "person" && bbox.Item6 != null) // Display if person is detected
                        {
                            DrawPerson(
                                frame,
                                bbox.Item1,
                                bbox.Item2,
                                bbox.Item3,
                                bbox.Item4,
                                bbox.Item6,
                                bbox.Item7
                            );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Cv2.Rectangle(frame, new OpenCvSharp.Point(bbox.Item1, bbox.Item2), new OpenCvSharp.Point(bbox.Item1 + bbox.Item3, bbox.Item2 + bbox.Item4), bbox.Item7, 1);
                            var caption = bbox.Item5;
                            Cv2.PutText(frame, caption, new OpenCvSharp.Point(bbox.Item1, bbox.Item2), HersheyFonts.HersheyComplex, 1, bbox.Item7, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Process and display the frame
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    UpdateDisplay(frame, imageControl);
                });
            };

            // Start video capture
            stream.Start();

            // Wait until cancellation is requested
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(20);
            }

            // Stop video capture
            stream.SignalToStop();
            stream.WaitForStop();
        }

        public async Task ProcessTask(System.Windows.Controls.Image imageControl, CancellationToken token, string URLreturnBbox, IDictionary<int, string> classNames, List<Scalar> colorList, ConcurrentDictionary<long, object> idFaceDictionary, BlockingCollection<Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, Scalar, DateTime>> ObjectDetectionBbox)
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (RunOTModel && ObjectTracking)
                {
                    await GetObjectDetectionBbox(URLreturnBbox, classNames, colorList, idFaceDictionary, ObjectDetectionBbox);
                }
            }
        }




        private async Task GetObjectDetectionBbox(string boundingBoxesUrl, IDictionary<int, string> classNames, List<Scalar> colorList, ConcurrentDictionary<long, object> idFaceDictionary, BlockingCollection<Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, Scalar, DateTime>> ObjectDetectionBbox)
        {
            var resultsList = await RunYolo(boundingBoxesUrl);

            // New dictionary to keep track of names already assigned
            var assignedNames = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (var results in resultsList)
            {
                if (!results.ContainsKey("class_")) continue;

                var classIndex = int.Parse(results["class_"].ToString());
                var className = classNames[classIndex];
                var classColor = colorList[classIndex];
                var topLeft = new OpenCvSharp.Point((long)results["x"], (long)results["y"]);
                var bottomRight = new OpenCvSharp.Point((long)results["w"], (long)results["h"]);
                string trackedName = null;
                long trackId = 0; // initialize with default value
                bool hasTrackId = results.ContainsKey("track_id");

                DateTime bboxTimestamp = DateTime.Parse(results["timestamp"].ToString());
                


                if (hasTrackId)
                {
                    trackId = (long)results["track_id"];
                }
                if (OTFaceRecognition && hasTrackId && className == "person" && !idFaceDictionary.ContainsKey(trackId))
                {
                    if (results.ContainsKey("result") && results["result"] != null)
                    {
                        var resultStr = results["result"].ToString();
                        // Check if this name has not been assigned already
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultStr) && !assignedNames.ContainsKey(resultStr))
                        {
                            // Remove any existing entries with the same value
                            foreach (var kvp in idFaceDictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Equals(resultStr)).ToList())
                            {
                                idFaceDictionary.TryRemove(kvp.Key, out _);
                            }
                            // Add the new entry
                            idFaceDictionary.TryAdd(trackId, resultStr);
                            // Add this name to the assigned names
                            assignedNames[resultStr] = new object();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (OTFaceRecognition && hasTrackId)
                {
                    trackedName = idFaceDictionary.ContainsKey(trackId)
                        ? $"{idFaceDictionary[trackId]} - ID {results["track_id"]}"
                        : null;
                }

                ObjectDetectionBbox.Add(Tuple.Create(
                    topLeft.X,                        // int
                    topLeft.Y,                        // int
                    bottomRight.X - topLeft.X,        // int
                    bottomRight.Y - topLeft.Y,        // int
                    className,                        // string
                    trackedName,                      // string
                    classColor,                       // Scalar
                    bboxTimestamp                     // DateTime
                    ));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Look at the return type for `Tuple.Create` taking 8 parameters.

Comment: @madreflection what do you mean? I can't really look at the return becauuse the error won't let me run the code. But it says its a tuple(datetime) which is really weird. I even tried chatgpt xD

Comment: You don't need to run the code to look at the return type. It's part of the method's signature.

Comment: Or look at the generic arguments for this type that you're using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-8?view=net-7.0 (particularly the last argument)

Comment: It's not weird. It's extensible. `Tuple<...>` only goes up to 8 type parameters and therefore 8 items, so the last item is a tuple containg all items after the 7th. You only have 1 `DateTime` item after the 7th so it's a 1-tuple of `DateTime`. The 8th type parameter is named `TRest` as in "the rest of the items".

Comment: If you had 9 items, `TRest` would be a 2-tuple of `DateTime` and whetever the 9th item's type is.

Comment: @madreflection thanks!!! I did not know this. I tried to solve this by: ObjectDetectionBbox.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, Scalar, DateTime>). Instead of using Tuple.Create<>, we use the new Tuple<>. I hope this is a good approach.

Comment: @madreflection But i dont think this is a good approach. What can i do then to be able to access this?

Comment: *"we use the new Tuple<>"* - No, that'st the *old* one. `ValueTuple<>` is the newer one.

Comment: Couple issues with this code:

You are nesting Ifs and inside a loop too, try to simplify this or chuck the logic in a logically named function(s) inside any if or loop. Each function should only do one thing.

For your question either make a class or struct to hold the variables, tuples are supposed to be for small amounts of immutable data. This means every change to a tuple duplicates it and doubles your memory usage (for the tuple).

Your functions are really long, this makes it had to read and bugfix down the track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Tuple.Create<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple.create?view=net-7.0#system-tuple-create-8(-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7)) has the following return type:

```cs
Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,Tuple<T8>>
```

So the last element is not the the type but tuple of single hence the error. Minimal reproducible example would be something like the following:

```cs
Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, double, DateTime> tup 
  = Tuple.Create(1, 1, 1, 1, "", "", 2.0, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

You can use the ctor for `Tuple` directly:

```cs
Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, double, DateTime> tup 
    = new Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, string, double, DateTime>(1, 1, 1, 1, "", "", 2.0, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

But in general I would recommend to avoid using tuples for such "big" number of items - just introduce a class/struct/record.

Comment: Or introduce a struct as it is just a container and has none of the class overheads. 
Either way then things can be given descriptive names.

Comment: @Slipoch depending on the actual usage `struct` can be not the optimal choice though. Due to value semantics it can even result in performance degradation if value is passed around a lot. Or in case of closures and/or threading (which `BlockingCollection` heavily hints on).

Comment: fascinating, thx for the info.